# Pandoc: Creating Tables, Markdown to PDF

Tags: pdf, pandoc

I am trying to create a table in a PDF using pandoc. The following table renders nicely in markdown:

```
| Type of Policy | Expansionary Policy | Contractionary Policy |
|---|---|----|
| Fiscal Policy | decrease t (increase di, increase C), increase government spending| opposite |
| Monetary Policy |decrease rr, decrease dr, buy securities (increase MS, decrease i, increase I)| opposite |
```

But when I convert using `pandoc notes.txt -o notes.pdf`, I get the following:

[image]

Is there a reason why the table is such a small width? And is there a way to easily change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [pandoc README](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables), in this kind of table you can set the spacing visually. Try e.g.

```
| Type of Policy  | Expansionary Policy                                                            | Contractionary Policy  |
|-----------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------------------|
| Fiscal Policy   | decrease t (increase di, increase C), increase government spending             | opposite               |
| Monetary Policy | decrease rr, decrease dr, buy securities (increase MS, decrease i, increase I) | opposite               |
```